# Combine multidimensional array by group python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
 [['test', '172.18.74.146', '13:05:43.834', '2015_08_07'], 
  ['test', '172.18.74.148', '12:27:39.016', '2015_08_07'], 
 ['blah', '172.18.74.149', '11:18:33.846', '2015_08_12'], 
 ['blah', '172.18.74.146', '12:27:38.985', '2015_08_12']]
```

I would like the final result to be grouped by date and the project name

```
[["test", "172.18.74.146, 172.18.74.148", "13:05:43.834, 12:27:39.016" ,
"2015_08_07"], etc..]
```

The names will not be the same for the given date.

How can I do this?  I tried using groupby.

```
for g, data in groupby(sorted(my_list, key=itemgetter(0)), itemgetter(0)):
   print(g)
   for elt in data:
     print(' ', elt)
```

but it didnt give me what I wanted.

Comment: Will the names be same for a given date?

Comment: @thefourtheye no they may not be, sorry in this example they are.

Comment: Do you want `groupby(mylist, key=itemgetter(0, 3))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass two keys to sorted, the name and date, then use `str.join` to concat the ip's and times

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

out = []

for _, v in groupby(sorted(data, key=itemgetter(0, 3)),key=itemgetter(0,3)):
    v = list(v)    
    ips = ", ".join([sub[1] for sub in v])
    tmes = ", ".join([sub[2] for sub in v])
    out.append([v[0][0], ips, tmes, v[0][-1]])

print(out)

['blah', '172.18.74.149, 172.18.74.146', '11:18:33.846, 12:27:38.985', '2015_08_12'], 
['test', '172.18.74.146, 172.18.74.148', '13:05:43.834, 12:27:39.016', '2015_08_07']]
```

Or without sorting using  dict to group:

```
d = {}

for nm, ip, tm, dte in data:
    key = nm, dte
    if key in d:
        v = d[key]
        v[1] += ", {}".format(ip)
        v[2] += ", {}".format(dte)
    else:
        d[key] = [nm, ip, tm, dte]

print(list(d.values()))
```

Output:

```
[['test', '172.18.74.146, 172.18.74.148', '13:05:43.834, 2015_08_07', '2015_08_07'], 
['blah', '172.18.74.149, 172.18.74.146', '11:18:33.846, 2015_08_12', '2015_08_12']]
```

Comment: @Ben, no worries, as far as your second comment goes I agree with DSM it is probably easier to ask a new question, I am not totally sure what output you expect, it would be easier add a sample of input and expected output to make it more obvious.