# Grouping elements in a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a few records which reads as follows:

```
list1= [['corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', 'springs'],
     ['corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', 'palm springs'],
     ['corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', 'edenvale']]
```

I want my record to look like this:

```
list2= ['corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', 'springs | palm springs | edenvale']
```

I wrote the following code to accomplish this:

```
for i in range(len(list1)-1):
    if list1[i][0] == list1[i+1][0]:
        list2.append([list1[i][0], list1[i][1] + "|" + list1[i + 1][1]])
    else:
        pass
```

This works if I have two elements in a list and are consecutive entries, it however fails if there are more than 2 items and are not consecutive.
Could anyone please point out a suitable way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `dict` for grouping.

To make things easier `defaultdict` is a good sub-class of `dict` for this case:

```
from collections import defaultdict
list1= [['corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', 'springs'],
     ['corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', 'palm springs'],
     ['corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', 'edenvale']]

def grouping(l):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for key,value in l:
        d[key].append(value)
    for key in d:
        d[key] = ' | '.join(d[key])
    return list(d.items())
list2 = grouping(list1)
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[('corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', 'springs | palm springs | edenvale')]
```

Testing:

```
list3= [['corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', 'springs'],
        ['corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', 'palm springs'],
        ['corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', 'edenvale'],
        ['testing 1243','hi'],
        ['corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', '123456'],
       ]
print(grouping(list3)
```

Output:

```
[('corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', 'springs | palm springs | edenvale | 123456'), ('testing 1243', 'hi')]
```

If you need to preserve the order, use `OrderedDict` instead:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def grouping(l):
    d = OrderedDict()
    for key,value in l:
        d.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
    for key in d:
        d[key] = ' | '.join(d[key])
    return list(d.items())
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer but I would like the order to be preserved as i need to append it back to a file , using a dictionary changes the order

Comment: @ArnabSharma I have updated the answer for order preservation. Please update your answer as well.

Comment: @ Alex Fung Thanks for your help, however one thing I would like to ask is whether this would be efficient for a large number of records?

Comment: This is a fast and pythonic way to group elements in python. `itertools` can be faster but I don't think there is going to be a big difference.

Comment: I am trying to implement this in MapReduce program, but when I use your code, the output says 'too many values to unpack' implying that there is something wrong in the line     for key,value in l:     . By any chance, is there any other way around this in python?

Comment: @Kourosh I think the list you pass into `grouping` is not a list of list/tuple. You might want to check what is the content of the list.

Comment: My list contains one tuple which holds two values, one string, and one float. Like this:  [(str, float)]

Comment: @Kourosh Maybe one of the elements is not a tuple with 2 values?

Answer (score 2):

Inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32077884/1233686) answer, adapted for your case with preserved order:

```
list1 = [['corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', 'springs'],
     ['corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', 'palm springs'],
     ['corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', 'edenvale']]

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

list2 = []
for _, v in groupby(sorted(list1, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0)):
    v = list(v)   
    cols = " | ".join([sub[1] for sub in v])
    list2.append([v[0][0], cols])

print(list2)
```

output:

```
[['corner grant and main reef road, new state area, springs', 'springs | palm springs | edenvale']]
```

Comment: This does not preserve order of the key as you will need to sort the list before group by.

Comment: Well, I have added another key between and first key's data order hasn't changed. Depends on internal implementation of `sorted` though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` funciton to group the elements in the list.

try;

```
from itertools import groupby
list1 = ....

grp = groupby(sorted(list1, key=lambda x: x[0]), lambda x: x[0])
list2 = [(key, " | ".join([x for _, x in group])) for key, group in grp]
```